# Is there a list of accidents due to poor communication in English?

Tags: radio-communications

I would like a list of accidents satisfying the following criteria:

- Poor communication between ATC and pilots was judged to be a major factor in the accident;
- English was the language of communication between ATC and the pilots; and
- The native language of the pilots and controller was the same, but not English.

I am not looking for discussion of whether using English is a good idea or not in these situations, whether its use played a role in these accidents, or whether better training in communications is needed. I just want a list of accidents where these conditions are met.

The poor communication need not necessarily have been attributed to insufficient knowledge of English.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE. Personally I think you question risks falling in the "shopping list" category, that is generally regarded as off-topic (and generally best suited for a discussion in chat). Stick around, gain some reputation and join us in chat! :)

Comment: Communication between ATC and flight crew is organised in *phrases*. That means the sentences to speak are predefined word by word. Therefore (implied that all participants use this phrases) it is more like using technical terms in your own language than speaking a foreign language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is resource finding. However if asked if a language barrier was attributed before, then it may pass.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me. Maybe there's not an immediate obvious answer to the question exactly as asked, but it would be rather pedantic to refuse to see the perfectly answerable, on-topic issue it represents

Comment: Are the current 4 VTC still valid after the edit?

Answer (score 5):

While in no way an exhaustive list, SKYbrary does provide a list of accidents and serious incidents which include air-ground communication as a causal factor. The list contains example of events, and is not meant to contain every single such event.

You can find it here: http://skybrary.aero/index.php/Accident_and_Serious_Incident_Reports:_AGC

You may also want to search for *communication* and related terms on The Aviation Herald: http://avherald.com/h?search_term=communication&dosearch=1&search.x=0&search.y=0

Comment: @Dave You may also want to check https://aviation-safety.net